# Batch: rd doesn't remove dir in a different shell

Tags: batch-file

I have a very strange error. I wrote a script which copies and extracts some files into one folder but before I do that, I remove the dir / old files like this:

```
SET destinationFolder=C:\MyFolder

IF EXIST %destinationFolder% ( 
        ECHO rd %destinationFolder% /S /Q
        rd %destinationFolder% /S /Q
        IF %errorlevel% == 0 ( ECHO --^> SUCCEED ) ELSE ( ECHO --^> FAILED & set /a errorCount+=1 & ECHO %errorlevel% )
) ELSE ( ECHO --^> SUCCEED: No files existent )
```

Well this works so far when I operate as an admin but not expected when I am not an admin.

If I open a non-admin-shell and run the batch the first time (no files exists) it works fine and also when I repeat it at the same shell (files from the same batch exists).

But, if I open another/new non-admin-shell(the previous is not running anymore) and I run the script (old files from the other batch are existent) it returns errorlevel 2 even though I check first if the dir is existent.

And the "funniest" thing is, when I run the command `rd %destinationFolder% /S /Q` in the same shell where it didn't work within the batch, it works fine as it should be!

Comment: You don't happen to be in the directory `C:\MyFolder` in one of those other shells? That usually is true for me if I want to delete or rename a folder.

Comment: if you mean the shells working path, then they both are at "C:\" but i do cd %destinationFolder%\WindowsX86\ within the script... if this matters...

Comment: If you stay in that directory then yes, it should break the script IMHO.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the value of the errorlevel instead of the variable

```
SET destinationFolder=C:\MyFolder

IF EXIST %destinationFolder% ( 
        ECHO rd %destinationFolder% /S /Q
        rd %destinationFolder% /S /Q || rem
        IF errorlevel 1 ( 
            ECHO --^> FAILED & set /a errorCount+=1 & ECHO %errorlevel% 
        ) ELSE ( 
            ECHO --^> SUCCEED 
        )
) ELSE ( 
    ECHO --^> SUCCEED: No files existent 
)
```

If you prefer to use the variable, avoid spaces after and before the equal signs and ensure that there is no value for the %errorlevel% variable. If it is explicitly set (sometimes i've seen it "initialized" to 0), error values from commands will no be asigned to it.

```
SET destinationFolder=C:\MyFolder

SET errorlevel=
IF EXIST %destinationFolder% ( 
        ECHO rd %destinationFolder% /S /Q
        rd %destinationFolder% /S /Q || rem
        IF not %errorlevel%==0 ( 
            ECHO --^> FAILED & set /a errorCount+=1 & ECHO %errorlevel% 
        ) ELSE ( 
            ECHO --^> SUCCEED 
        )
) ELSE ( 
    ECHO --^> SUCCEED: No files existent 
)
```

EDIT:

In both samples, output of rd needs to be chained to another command to execute on failed execution. Without it, rd does not return error codes.

Comment: thanks, but the errorlevel is working correct.... its just about the RD command which doesn´t work/ delete my folder

Comment: Well, after trying some more, in your code and in my code, errorlevel test on rd command DOES NOT WORK. rd doesn't return/change errorlevel codes, or at least not without tricks. It's necessary to, by example, chain command output to rem command to get the desired behaviour. So, it should read `rd %destination% || rem ` and then the errorlevel will work. I will update answer to reflect this, and will continue to try to reproduce your error.

Comment: ok, as MCND said, RD doesn´t change the Errorlevel so you have to check it with pipes.

i solved it like this:

    ( rd %destinationFolder% /S /Q && ECHO --^> SUCCEED ) || ( ECHO --^> FAILED & set /a errorCount+=1 ) 


if there is a nicer way to do this, please tell me :)

Answer (score 0):

change this code

```
SET destinationFolder=C:\MyFolder
....
    rd %destinationFolder% /S /Q
    IF %errorlevel% == 0 (....
```

to this:

```
SET "destinationFolder=C:\MyFolder\"
....
    rd "%destinationFolder%" /S /Q || rem
    IF %errorlevel%==0 (....
```

Comment: This works:

( rd %destinationFolder% /S /Q && ECHO --^> SUCCEED ) || ( ECHO --^> FAILED & set /a errorCount+=1 )